# How can I validate something without using regular expressions in C#?

Tags: c#, validation

HI how can I validate a string, but without using regular expressions. For example how can validate this: xxx/xxxx where x is a digit? thanks

Comment: You always can check character one by one if the pattern stay simple, but why don't you want to use regexp. They are perfect for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like that:

```
bool ValidateExpression(string expression)
{
    string[] parts = expression.Split("/");

    if (
        parts.Length != 2
        || parts[0].Length != 3
        || parts[1].Length != 4
    ) return false;

    int parsed;
    return Int32.TryParse(parts[0], out parsed) && Int32.TryParse(parts[1], out parsed);    
}
```

To be used later as

```
bool isValid = ValidateExpression("123/4567");
```

Comment: TryParse may not be recommended because the function active exception mechanism made some multiplication. All that is costly for CPU and what you want is just a range comparaison. The advantage of not using regulars expressions will be performance, no ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Char.IsDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58.aspx) to check if characters are a digit. For your specific case, you could do something like this:

```
public bool IsMyStringValid(string myString)
{
  foreach(var c in myString)
    if(!Char.IsDigit() && !c == '/') return false;

  return true;
}
```

This is actually more specific to your case (3 digits, one '/' at index 3, followed by 4 digits):

```
public bool IsMyStringValid(string myString)
{
  if(myString.Length != 8) return false;

  for(var i = 0; i <8, i++)
    if(!Char.IsDigit(myString[i]) || (i == 3 && myString[i] == '/') return false;

  return true;
}
```

Comment: @Sparky, fair point. Added a second implementation to account for the exact string in OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

For that specific format you can use:

```
bool valid =
  value.Length == 8 &&
  value.Take(3).All(Char.IsDigit) &&
  value[3] == '/' &&
  value.Skip(4).All(Char.IsDigit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    public bool ValidateString(string str)
    {
        var strArr = str.Split('/');
        return strArr[0].All(char.IsDigit) && strArr[1].All(char.IsDigit);
    }
```

hope this help;

Comment: And what would happen if the string contained all digits?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the .All to check something like this so no matter what the string is
if there is a non digit in it, it will not pass

```
    public static bool IsMyStringValid(string strValidateString)
    {
        bool boolIsValid = false;
        if (strValidateString.All(Char.IsDigit))
        {
            boolIsValid = true; 
        }
        return boolIsValid; 
    }
```